# Negative word matching with regular expressions

Tags: html, regex, regex-negation

I want to be able to construct a regular expression which searches for a particular pattern in some HTML code where one parameter is negated (i.e. find x where y is **NOT** present).

**Example:** I want to find image width parameters where width does not equal "500".

- `width="640" height="360"` **would match**
- `width="500" height="360"` **would NOT match**

I'm using a search & replace plugin for wordpress to run the regular expression - http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/search-regex - it just uses a generic regex syntax

I'm able to match simple queries but I'm afraid negation is a bit beyond me - any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks - David

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a [*negative lookahead*](http://ourcraft.wordpress.com/2009/03/25/positive-examples-of-positive-and-negative-lookahead/):

```
width="(?!500)([^"]+)"
```

Answer (score 1):

The regex way to do negation would be negative lookaheads, see [here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html). This would look like

```
<img [^>]*width=(?!"500")
```

But it would be far easier and less errorprone to not use regex and use a HTML parser instead.